# Google Keep sync is delayed or doesn't happen when a long time between logins

Tags: google-keep

I have a dual installation of Windows & Ubuntu and I use Google Keep Chrome app on both the OSes as well as on my Android phone. I boot into Ubuntu about once a month or so. The problem I am having is that the Keep chrome app on Ubuntu shows some older notes that I have deleted few weeks back. Those notes don't show up on other Keep apps or on keep.google.com. I expect those noted to be deleted from all Keep apps because the updated content is stored on Google's servers & all apps should be in sync.

Comment: How long do you wait for the data to sync?

Comment: @AlE. about 15-20 minutes. I don't use Ubuntu much.

Comment: Is there an option to "Refresh", as there is with the web version?

Comment: Have you tried logging out of Google and logging back in? I expect that the cookie keeping track of you has probably expired.